# telerik. RadGrid get DataKeyField value in client event

Tags: javascript, telerik, telerik-grid

How can i get DataKeyField value in my javascript event OnHierarchyExpanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the telerik forums that shows (the linked post and the one below it) how to do what it sounds like you're asking.
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/retrieve-client-side-id-of-selected-row-datakeyvalue.aspx#891960